# Elixir: Decimal cast and dont allow negative numbers

Tags: elixir

Hello I receive a value and this value cannot be negative, only positive, I would like to return a custom error if it is negative and proceed to the pipe if it is negative.

i have this at moment:

```
 def call(%{"id" => id, "value" => value}, operation) do
    Multi.new()
    |> Multi.run(:account, fn repo, _changes -> get_account(repo, id) end)
    |> Multi.run(:update_balance, fn repo, %{account: account} ->
      update_balance(repo, account, value, operation)
    end)
  end
  defp update_balance(repo, account, value, operation) do
    account
    |> operation(value, operation)
    |> update_account(repo, account)
  end
  defp operation(%Account{balance: balance}, value, operation) do
    value
    |> Decimal.cast()
    |> handle_cast(balance, operation)
  end

  defp handle_cast({:ok, value}, balance, :deposit), do: Decimal.add(balance, value)
  defp handle_cast({:ok, value}, balance, :withdraw), do: Decimal.sub(balance, value)
  defp handle_cast(:error, _balance, _operation), do: {:error, "Invalid operation!"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my last comment, `Decimal` is a different "type", which is greater than integers.

Luckily, though, `Decimal` provides `gt?`, `lt?` and `compare` functions which you can use to compare `Decimal`s to integers. A somewhat clean solution, to alter your code as little as possible, would be to add a small extra function before `handle_cast` and another definition for `handle_cast`. Something like this:

```rb
defp operation(%Account{balance: balance}, value, operation) do
  value
  |> Decimal.cast()
  |> maybe_positive?()
  |> handle_cast(balance, operation)
end

defp maybe_positive?({:ok, value}) do
  case Decimal.compare?(value, 0) do
    :lt -> {:error, :negative_number}
    :gt -> {:ok, value}
  end
end

defp maybe_positive?(error), do: error

defp handle_cast({:error, :negative_number}, _balance, _operation) do
  {:error, "Number must be positive"}
end
defp handle_cast({:ok, value}, balance, :deposit), do: Decimal.add(balance, value)
...
```

That way if it's a negative number it goes through the `{:error, :negative_number}` case from `handle_cast`, and if it's positive or the `cast` failed for some reason, it will go through the other `handle_cast` validations you already have

Comment: I tried it this way, but still negative numbers are accepted, and I also need to cast to decimal before checking if it's negative.

Comment: if I use the value as a string, it remains negative, but if I use the number it works.

Comment: Yes, if it's a string it won't work because strings are always greater than numbers. `"2" < 3` won't fail, but will return `false`. I've just updated the answer with a couple more options

Comment: I think I understand, in case I need to check in my handle_cast if the number is negative.

If I do that, will I not need these two operations?

defp operation (_account, value, _operation) when value <0 do
  {: error, "Number must be positive"}
end
defp operation (_account, "-" <> _value, _operation) do
  {: error, "Number must be positive"}
end

Comment: could you show what the best final solution would look like?

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you just add the one to `handle_cast`, you won't need to alter `operation`, so that's the simplest and IMO most correct solution

Comment: I tried with both operations and functions, but with this handle_cast / 4 knob it still allows negative numbers

Comment: I don’t know why but with that here I still accept negative numbers and string with - :   defp handle_cast({:ok, value}, _balance, _operation) when value < 0 do
    {:error, "Number must be positive"}
  end

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm updating the answer. `Decimal` is a different type and, like strings, it will also always be greater than just integers

Comment: Take a look now. That should do it

Comment: Thank you very much, I started now at the elixir and with your explanation, it seemed clearer how to solve problems in this way, thank you.

Comment: @sbacarob you might want to check my answer for another handy way to handle this :)

Answer (score 4):

While the answer by @sbacarob is perfectly correct, I would post this for the sake of convenience.

`Decimal` is a [plain struct](https://github.com/ericmj/decimal/blob/master/lib/decimal.ex#L112), so one might use its internals to handle negatives with guards. This will work with modern versions of Elixir ≥ 1.11 and OTP ≥ 23.

```rb
defguard is_decimal_positive(value)
    when is_map(value) and
         value.__struct__ == Decimal and 
         value.sign == 1
```

See [`Kernel.defguard/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#defguard/1) for details. And use it as

```rb
defp operation(%Account{balance: balance}, value, operation) do
  value
  |> Decimal.cast()
  |> handle_cast(balance, operation)
end

defp handle_cast({:ok, value}, balance, _) 
    when is_decimal_positive(value),
  do: Decimal.add(balance, value)

defp handle_cast(_error, _balance, _),
  do: {:error, "Number must be positive decimal"}
```

Comment: That's pretty amazing! I was not aware of it, but definitely allows for cleaner code without too much hustle

Comment: Well, I provided a [PR to `Decimal`](https://github.com/ericmj/decimal/pull/168) to support guards natively. Let’s see.

Comment: @Aleksei Matiushkin thank u great solution bro.

Answer (score 2):

Ta fazendo o NLW de ELixir tambem!
Eu fiz assim e funcionou:

Repositorio: https://github.com/librity/nlw_elixir

```
defmodule Rocketpay.Accounts.Operation do
  alias Ecto.Multi
  alias Rocketpay.Account

  def call(%{"id" => id, "value" => value}, operation) do
    fetch_account_operation_name = build_fetch_account_operation_name(operation)

    Multi.new()
    |> Multi.run(
      fetch_account_operation_name,
      fn repo, _previous -> fetch_account(repo, id) end
    )
    |> Multi.run(operation, fn repo, fetch_result ->
      account = Map.get(fetch_result, fetch_account_operation_name)

      update_balance(repo, account, value, operation)
    end)
  end

  defp fetch_account(repo, id) do
    case repo.get(Account, id) do
      nil -> {:error, "Account not found."}
      account -> {:ok, account}
    end
  end

  defp update_balance(repo, account, value, operation) do
    account
    |> calculate_new_balance(value, operation)
    |> update_account(account, repo)
  end

  defp calculate_new_balance(%Account{balance: balance}, value, operation) do
    value
    |> Decimal.cast()
    |> validate_greater_than_zero()
    |> handle_cast(balance, operation)
  end

  defp validate_greater_than_zero({:ok, casted_value}) do
    case Decimal.compare(casted_value, 0) do
      :lt -> :error
      :eq -> :error
      :gt -> {:ok, casted_value}
    end
  end

  defp validate_greater_than_zero(:error), do: :error

  defp handle_cast({:ok, valid_value}, balance, :deposit), do: Decimal.add(balance, valid_value)
  defp handle_cast({:ok, valid_value}, balance, :withdraw), do: Decimal.sub(balance, valid_value)

  defp handle_cast(:error, _balance, :deposit), do: {:error, "Invalid deposit value."}
  defp handle_cast(:error, _balance, :withdraw), do: {:error, "Invalid withdraw value."}

  defp update_account({:error, _reason} = error, _account, _repo), do: error

  defp update_account(new_balance, account, repo) do
    account
    |> Account.changeset(%{balance: new_balance})
    |> repo.update()
  end

  defp build_fetch_account_operation_name(operation),
    do: "fetch_#{operation}_account" |> String.to_atom()
end
```